# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

Error is on line #5 of the code below:

```
public class FirstController : Controller{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        OtherController OtherController = new OtherController();
        return OtherController.Index();
    }
}
```

Then the `OtherController`:

```
public class OtherController : Controller{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {            
        //Tasks...
        //await...
        return View();
    }   
}
```

I tried this and get the same error on line #5:

```
public class FirstController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        OtherController OtherController = new OtherController();
        return OtherController.Index();
    }
}
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: you need an `await` call somewhere in the body before they compiler is going to set up the `Task<ActionResult>` return for you

Comment: @DarrenKopp I don't need one, it suggested I have one. I do have one in `OtherController` but not in `FirstController`, but the error I'm getting is a conversion issue and the only reason I changed `FirstController` to `async` was so there wouldn't be conversion issues, but async on `First` is not needed, it's what I tried after I got errors with `First` not being async.

Comment: yes, you do. for example. if you put `await Task.Delay(100)` before `return View()` in the second one, the compiler will no longer complain. The reason the first works is because IT returns `Task<ActionResult>`

Comment: Me not using `await` in `FirstController` just comes up as a warning, not an error, it runs without await. The compiler is complaining on the first controller, not the second one.

Comment: For example, If i change FirstController to `public ActionResult Index()` since it's not async, then I get the same error.

Comment: What if you went `return await OtherController.Index();` instead?

Comment: Shall I post that as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `await` the result of calling `OtherController.Index();` as this method is marked as `async`. Because you are awaiting that call, your `FirstController.Index` method also needs to be marked as `async`.

In your `FirstController.Index` method you would therefore have:

```
return await OtherController.Index();
```